# Re activate jquery click method after setting it to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click method which I would like to deactivate when a certain element has a class.

```
if($('.returningUserPanel').hasClass('is-active')){
   $('.item-cart .panel-trigger').click(false);
}
```

Here above I set the click method to false, but I want to reactive this click method but it is not as simple to set `.click(true)` to true?

```
$('.continue-shopping-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.item-cart .panel-trigger').click(true);
    $('.returningUserPanel').removeClass('is-active is-visible');
})
```

Could somebody help me out with this?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting `true`/`false` to do.  It's not how you enable/disable the events: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Why don't you have a condition in the event listener that checks if the element has a class?

Comment: Might be better to check this within the click handler itself:  `$(".panel-trigger").on("click", function() { if($('.returningUserPanel').hasClass('is-active')) return false; /* else continue */ });`

Comment: You can check hasclass inside the click event.
If true then you can write any logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to keep a reference to the click handler such as `function myClickHandler = fucntion() {}` and set it:
**on** - `$('.item-cart .panel-trigger').click(myClickHandler);`
and **[off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** - `$('.item-cart .panel-trigger').off("click");`
according to your logic.

But a much more clean solution is to keep the handler on and inside decide whether to do this or that.